# Best way to split a large String in large number of sub string

Tags: string, c#-4.0, split, substring

I want to split a large string file into large number of very small sub string and then store it so that i can use all sub string further in my program. what will be best way to do so.my program is in C# so Please provide solution only in C#.

Here is input File : https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/code-monk-hashing/problems/monk-in-the-land-of-pokemons/4326354c-2-input-4326316.txt?Signature=mtbhaQ2%2F6VRAH8A9OfZTSAX6oTQ%3D&Expires=1457955770&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ

all i want to get all number separated by white space in a collection.
is it possible that i can read all number separated by white space without saving them in collection?

**Question:** 
Monk has to visit a land where strange creatures, known as Pokemons, roam around in the wild. Each Pokemon in the land will attack any visitor. They can only be pacified by feeding them their favorite food.

The Pokemon of type X eats one food item of type X.

Monk knows that he will encounter N ponds on the way. At each pond, he will find a food item and then encounter a Pokemon. The i'th pond has the food item of type Ai and the Pokemon of type Bi.

The monk can feed the item at the i'th pond to the Pokemon at the pond if the type matches. Monk may have to carry some food items with him before leaving so as to feed all the Pokemons. Help him find the number of items he must carry, to be to able to pass through the land safely.

Input:
The first line contains T, denoting the number of test cases. Then, T test cases follow.
The first line of each test case contains an integer N. Then, N lines follow.
Each line consists of 2 space-separated integers Ai and Bi.

Output: For each test case, print the answer in a new line.

Constraints:
1 ≤ T ≤ 10
1 ≤ N ≤ 105
1 ≤ Ai, Bi ≤ 106

Code:

```html
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class MyClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int TestCaseNo = Int32.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine().Trim());
        int TestCase;
        for (int j = 0; j < TestCaseNo; j++)
        {
            LinkedList<int> numbers = new LinkedList<int>();
            numbers.Clear();
            int count = 0;
            TestCase = Int32.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine().Trim());

            for (int i = 0; i < TestCase; i++)
            {

                string line = System.Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                string[] temp = line.Split(' ');
                if (Int32.Parse(temp[0]) == Int32.Parse(temp[1]))
                { }
                else
                {
                    if (numbers.Contains(Int32.Parse(temp[1])))
                    {
                        numbers.Remove(Int32.Parse(temp[1]));
                        numbers.AddFirst(Int32.Parse(temp[0]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numbers.AddFirst(Int32.Parse(temp[0]));
                        count++;
                    }

                }
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the condition to split the string?

Comment: Have you read the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) part of the FAQ? Please show us what you have tried and were you are not getting further. Then we'll sure help you make it work!

Comment: What have you tried? you'll get more help (generally)  if you show what you've done

Comment: i used  split method of a string .(string[] temp = line.Split(' ');) but as output have too many number performance of my program is bad.

Comment: It would be better to show us the code you've used and maybe we can help improve the performance of it, rather than just asking us to give you new code.

Comment: @Nanhydrin : i have added question and my code too. please check